# Regarding migrating searchview on appcompat

Tags: android, android-fragments, menuitem, android-support-library, searchview

I am migrating search view Item provided  in action bar using support library .Here I have done as mentioned in doc but still it is giving error while creating options menu.Please tell me where I have done wrong.Here is my code.

**contacts_list_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:com.utteru.ui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- The search menu item. Honeycomb and above uses an ActionView or specifically a SearchView
         which expands within the Action Bar directly. Note the initial collapsed state set using
         collapseActionView in the showAsAction attribute. -->

    <group
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_group">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"

        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="@string/menu_search" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/refresh_group">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh"

        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_popup_sync"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="@string/menu_search" />
</group>
</menu>
```

**ContactsListFragment.java**

```
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo;
import android.support.v4.BuildConfig;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;


public class ContactsListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "ContactsAccessFragment";
    private static final String STATE_PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_KEY =
            "com.Utteru.ui.SELECTED_ITEM";
    ArrayList<AccessContactDto> allcontacts;
    ArrayList<AccessContactDto> databasecontacts;
    TextView textempty;

    public Context mContext;
    private AccessContactAdapter mAdapter;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader; // Handles loading the contact image in a background thread


    // Stores the previously selected search item so that on a configuration change the same item
    // can be reselected again
    private int mPreviouslySelectedSearchItem = 0;

    // Whether or not the search query has changed since the last time the loader was refreshed
    private boolean mSearchQueryChanged;

    // Whether or not this fragment is showing in a two-pane layout
    private boolean mIsTwoPaneLayout;

    // Whether or not this is a search result view of this fragment, only used on pre-honeycomb
    // OS versions as search results are shown in-line via Action Bar search from honeycomb onward
    private boolean mIsSearchResultView = false;

    /**
     * Fragments require an empty constructor.
     */
    public ContactsListFragment() {

    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mIsTwoPaneLayout = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.has_two_panes);

        getActivity().setTitle("");
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // If we're restoring state after this fragment was recreated then
            // retrieve previous search term and previously selected search
            // result.
            mPreviouslySelectedSearchItem =
                    savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_KEY, 0);
        }
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity(), CommonUtility.getListPreferredItemHeight(getActivity())) {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap processBitmap(Object data) {
                // This gets called in a background thread and passed the data from
                // ImageLoader.loadImage().
                return loadContactPhotoThumbnail((String) data, getImageSize());
            }
        };

        // Set a placeholder loading image for the image loader
        mImageLoader.setLoadingImage(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture_holo_light);

        // Add a cache to the image loader
        mImageLoader.addImageCache(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), 0.1f);
        mContext = getActivity().getBaseContext();
        new loadData().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the list fragment layout

        View all_contacts_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_fragment, container, false);
        textempty = (TextView)all_contacts_view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        textempty.setText("No contacts found");
        return all_contacts_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        AccessContactDto cdto = (AccessContactDto) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Log.e("number on click",""+cdto.getMobile_number());
        cdto=UserService.getUserServiceInstance(mContext).getAccessConDataByNumber(cdto.getMobile_number());


        if(cdto==null)
            cdto = (AccessContactDto) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        else
            Log.e("mumber not mull from db","number not null from db");


        Intent detailsActivity = new Intent(mContext, ContactDetailActivity.class);
        detailsActivity.putExtra("selected_con", cdto);
        startActivity(detailsActivity);
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation1, R.anim.animation2);
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Let this fragment contribute menu items
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // Set up ListView, assign adapter and set some listeners. The adapter was previously
        // created in onCreate().
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        getListView().setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
                // Pause image loader to ensure smoother scrolling when flinging
                if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                    mImageLoader.setPauseWork(true);
                } else {
                    mImageLoader.setPauseWork(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }
        });


        if (mIsTwoPaneLayout) {

            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
        if (mPreviouslySelectedSearchItem == 0) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


        mImageLoader.setPauseWork(false);
    }





    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.clear();
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_list_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.main_menu_group, true);
        if (mIsSearchResultView) {
            searchItem.setVisible(false);
        }

        if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {

            final SearchManager searchManager =
                    (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

            searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                    searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String queryText) {


                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                    Log.e("on query text change ","on query text change");
                    if (newText != null && !newText.equals(""))
                    {
                        ArrayList<AccessContactDto> filterList = new ArrayList<AccessContactDto>();

                        for (AccessContactDto a : allcontacts) {
                            if (a.getDisplay_name().toLowerCase().startsWith(newText.toLowerCase())) {
                                filterList.add(a);
                                continue;
                            }


                            getListView().setAdapter(new AccessContactAdapter(filterList, getActivity(), mImageLoader));
                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                    else{
                        getListView().setAdapter(new AccessContactAdapter(allcontacts, getActivity(), mImageLoader));
                        return true;
                    }

                }

            });

        }
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.menu_search:
                if (!Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
                    getActivity().onSearchRequested();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.refresh:
                if (CommonUtility.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {

                    final Account account = new Account(Constants.ACCOUNT_NAME, Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
                    bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
                    ContentResolver.requestSync(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, bundle);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
//                        @Override
//                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
//                        }
//
//                        @Override
//                        public void onFinish() {
//
//                        }
//                    }.start();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet Connection Required!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private Bitmap loadContactPhotoThumbnail(String photoData, int imageSize) {

        if (!isAdded() || getActivity() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;

        try {
            Uri thumbUri;
            if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {
                thumbUri = Uri.parse(photoData);
            } else {

                final Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, photoData);

                thumbUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
            }

            afd = getActivity().getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(thumbUri, "r");

            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = afd.getFileDescriptor();

            if (fileDescriptor != null) {

                return ImageLoader.decodeSampledBitmapFromDescriptor(
                        fileDescriptor, imageSize, imageSize);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Contact photo thumbnail not found for contact " + photoData
                        + ": " + e.toString());
            }
        } finally {

            if (afd != null) {
                try {
                    afd.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<AccessContactDto> readContactsNew() {
        ArrayList<AccessContactDto> list = new ArrayList<AccessContactDto>();
        AccessContactDto adto;
        Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String photouri= phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
            String contact_id= phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));
            Uri con_uri= Contacts.getLookupUri(phones.getLong(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)), phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY)));
            adto = new AccessContactDto(contact_id, name, null, phoneNumber, null, photouri, con_uri.toString(),null,null,null);
            list.add(adto);
        }
        phones.close();
        return list;
    }


    public class loadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>

    {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            mAdapter = new AccessContactAdapter(allcontacts, getActivity(), mImageLoader);
            if(getActivity()!=null)
            getListView().setAdapter(mAdapter);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            allcontacts = readContactsNew();

//            databasecontacts = UserService.getUserServiceInstance(mContext).getAllAccessContacts();
//            allcontacts.removeAll(databasecontacts);
//            allcontacts.addAll(databasecontacts);
            Collections.sort(allcontacts, new Comparator<AccessContactDto>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(AccessContactDto lhs, AccessContactDto rhs) {

                    return lhs.getDisplay_name().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getDisplay_name());
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**ContactsListActivity.java**

```
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPagerAdapter;


public class ContactsListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    DemoCollectionPagerAdapter mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ContactDetailFragment mContactDetailFragment;
    private boolean isTwoPaneLayout;
    AccountManager mAccountManager;
    Boolean checkAccount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter = new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.color.purple));
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);
        isTwoPaneLayout = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.has_two_panes);
        PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
        pagerTabStrip.setTextSpacing(0);
        pagerTabStrip.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
        pagerTabStrip.setTextSize(1, 20);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.remove("android:support:fragments");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        startActivity(new Intent(ContactsListActivity.this, MenuScreen.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.card_rotate_in, R.anim.card_rotate_out);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(CommonUtility.dialog!=null){
            CommonUtility.dialog.dismiss();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        boolean isSearchResultView = false;
        return !isSearchResultView && super.onSearchRequested();
    }

    public static class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter {

        protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[]{"All Contacts", "Access Contacts"};
        protected final int[] ICONS = new int[]{
                R.drawable.all_contact,
                R.drawable.access_contacts
        };
        private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

        public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {

            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    // All Contacts Fragment
                    return new ContactsListFragment();
                case 1:
                    // Access Contacts Fragment
                    return new ContactsAccessFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return DemoCollectionPagerAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconResId(int index) {
            return ICONS[index % ICONS.length];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCount;
        }

        public void setCount(int count) {
            if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
                mCount = count;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.hello.ContactsListFragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu(ContactsListFragment.java:236)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performPrepareOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1882)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:2020)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel(FragmentActivity.java:459)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnPreparePanel(ActionBarActivity.java:280)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onPreparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:84)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1006)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1182)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:79)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:115)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```